# transform: scale transition broken on text when covered with fixed div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a problem with transition of a transform: scale on text on a button element when partially covered by fixed div.

The text dissapears during the animation and then reappears after it has finished.

Here is the code for the button

CSS:

```
.social-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #222222;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    line-height: 90px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: .99;
    border-radius: 28%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.59);
    transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.59);
}
.social-button:before {
    content: ' ';
    background-color: #000;
    width: 120%;
    height: 120%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: -110%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.59);
    transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.59);
}
.social-button .fa {
    font-size: 38px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.59);
    transition: all 0.35s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.59);
}
.social-button.mail:before{
    background-color: #4a7f45;
}
.social-button.mail .fa{
    margin-top: -7px;
    color: #4a7f45;
}
.social-button:focus:before, .social-button:hover:before {
    top: -10%;
    left: -10%;
}
.social-button:focus .fa, .social-button:hover .fa {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="mailto:mail@kemoke.net" class="social-button mail"><i class="fa fa envelope"></i></a>
```

This problem happens on my site whenever the navbar covers these buttons.
This seems to only happen on chrome.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to explain it, i edited it now.

Comment: I've tried changing z-index, no effect. It only seems to happen on chrome though, since on edge and firefox it works fine.

Comment: ...I suspect we'll need a more complete demo as there is no "fixed div", "button" or "text" in your code...just a link. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oLWrpg

Comment: Come to my page http://kemoke.net/ and scroll down until you overlap the navbar with social buttons, then try to hover over them.

Comment: Nope, we shouldn't have to go away from Stack Overflow to see the issue.

Comment: It doesnt seem to happen in an iframe, thats why i cant link you like that.